# image folder overwrite on window azure

Tags: azure

i am new to the windows azure web application deployment.

i developed mvc web application and publish to the windows azure cloud platform.
i have one folder name Messages, that contains the images that i have upload via application.
 now after user upload images in web app once the app is published on cloud.
next time when i republish the application to the cloud
that "Messages" folder contents (images) are removed.
can you please help me, how to resolve this?

Regards, Brijesh vaidya

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the expected behavior. Anytime you redeploy your application, new VMs are created for your application. You should not store anything that you want to persist on VM. Instead store them in blob storage. So in your case, you should upload the image and once the image is uploaded, transfer it to blob storage. You may want to check out this hands-on-lab in Azure training kit: https://github.com/WindowsAzure-TrainingKit/HOL-IntroToCloudServices-VS2012

Comment: i am very new to the windows azure, can you please provide the detail, how should i upload image to the blob, because i created the blob url for the image storage in the existing application.

Comment: If you're new to Windows Azure, I would **strongly recommend** going through Windows Azure Training Kit **before** you start writing code. The training kit has many hands on labs which will help you understand Windows Azure platform.